# IOS HTML5 app Facebook Login failure when 'Add to Home' screen used

Tags: php, ios, facebook, html

I have been working on a website that has a mobile version. Integrated into the site is a bit of code that allows users with FB to register without having to fill out a form. If the user meets any of the following conditions all is well

- Uses ANY desktop browser
- Users ANY mobile browser

The FB just works. However as soon as I do an 'Add to Homescreen' with IOS to make the app look and perform like a native app, when anyone uses the FB signup I get the

'Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration: One or more of the given URL's is not allowed by the Apps settings. It must match the Website URL or the Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App domains'

I am assuming that once you use the add to home screen, and the app gets its own instanced browser, the URL changes, likely some form of localhost derivation maybe?

I can't find any definitive answers to fixing this, and was wondering if anyone else had experienced this HTML5 IOS app problem?

Comment: Been struggling with this exact thing for a couple of days now. Something about the way cross-domain communication gets handled in homescreen apps seems to just seriously spook the facebook stuff.

Anybody have any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the dev of the extension I was using will be working on a different authentication flow, so not giving this any more dev time